# javax.jdo.JDOException: string property file is too long. It cannot exceed 1000000 characters

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I try to upload a small TXT file (4KB) to Google App Engine DataStore. When I test the application localy I have no problems and the file gets saved successfully; but when i try in GAE I get the following error:

```
javax.jdo.JDOException: string property file is too long.  It cannot exceed 1000000 characters.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: string property file is too long.  It cannot exceed 1000000 characters
```

In GAE console, the logs said the following:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:480)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:380)
at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:746)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
```

The JDO mapping of the entity that contains the file is the following:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class AppointmentEntity implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;    
    @Persistent(serialized = "true")
    private DownloadableFile file;
```

And DownloadableFile is:

```
public class DownloadableFile implements Serializable {
    private byte[] content;
    private String filename;
    private String mimeType;
```

Any ideas of whats wrong? I read something about session size and entity size, but the small filesize makes me discard these theories.

Comment: The maximum size per datastore entity is [1MB](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Datastore_Statistics). Seeing as your text file is only 4KB, could you somehow be adding it to the DS multiple times? It might explain why you're hitting the limit.

Comment: I don't think so, the update is executed only once. If the size of the entity would be larger than 1MB, the local datastore would complain?

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting your small file in the blobstore and then storing the blobkey in the datastore:

```
@PersistenceCapable()
public class FileEntity   {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    protected Key key;


    @Persistent
    private BlobKey blobKey;

}




private void createBlobStoreEntity() throws IOException{
        final PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        final FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
        final AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(Const.CONTENT_TYPE_PLAIN);
        final String path = file.getFullPath();
        final FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Channels.newWriter(writeChannel, "UTF8"));
        try {

            out.println(txt);
            out.close();
            writeChannel.closeFinally();
            final BlobKey key = fileService.getBlobKey(file);

            final ValueBlobStore store = new
                    FileEntity(key);

            pm.makePersistent(store);
            pm.flush();

        }
        finally {
            out.close();
            pm.close();
        }
    }
```